# pandas dataframe apply lambda index error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code

```
df2['TaxAccNo4'] = df2['TaxAccNo2'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
df2['TaxAccNo3'] = df2['TaxAccNo2'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[1])
```

where df2 is:

```
     TaxAccNo2    
0    00001379.1   
1    00182218
```

When I run the code I get

```
     TaxAccNo2   TaxAccNo4
0    00001379.1  00001379
1    00182218    00182218
```

and IndexError: list index out of range for TaxAccNo3,

```
     TaxAccNo2   TaxAccNo4   TaxAccNo3
0    00001379.1  00001379    1
1    00182218    00182218
```

How do I fix my code to produce that output? I'm assuming its giving me the error because Index 1 doesn't have '.' but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Hy, I was reviewing your code, the problem is that when you use the method split() in a string the returned object is a list, and this is causing the index error, as you pointed. The solution I encountered if very simple, use a conditional in your code to prevent it from calling this index for shorter lists as follows. Hope it helps.

```
df2['TaxAccNo3'] = df2['TaxAccNo2'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[1] if len(x.split('.'))>1 else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the problem is that `"00182218".split(".")` doesn't have a `[1]` index, since it's the list `["00182218"]`.

A simple solution without affecting too much the code is to use a [... if ... else ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python) ternary operator:

```
df2['TaxAccNo4'] = df2['TaxAccNo2'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
df2['TaxAccNo3'] = df2['TaxAccNo2'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[1] if '.' in x else '')
```

Where the last `''` is an empty string, the value with which you will fill 'TaxAccNo3' if  'TaxAccNo2' doesn't have a dot (you can replace it if you want other behaviour).

The semantic is: put `x.split('.')[1]` in `df2['TaxAccNo3']` if `x` contains a dot, otherwise put an empty string.